# Set the size of text in label in LWUIT j2me

Tags: java-me, fonts, label, lwuit

Is there any way to set the size(means font size,i want to make my text larger contaning font size of 17-20) of the text in the label in LWUIT for J2ME.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

You can set the large text by two ways.

1. Use ResourceEdit and Create the new Large Font in Font tab. Then change the Label#Unselected font to that new Large Font.
2. Use following code,

`new Label("Sample").getStyle().setFont(Font.createSystemFont(Font.FACE_SYSTEM, Font.STYLE_PLAIN, Font.SIZE_LARGE));`

For more info see this article, [Using Font with LWUIT](http://download.oracle.com/javame/dev-tools/lwuit-1.4/LWUIT_Developer_Guide_HTML/cjbcgcdd.html#z400088e1295971)